# Variadic template specilization

Tags: c++, templates, variadic-templates, template-specialization, static-assert

So I was trying the custom literal operator in order to implement binary literals. However it seems I am doing something wrong with the template specialization. The static_assert is evaluated while it shouldn't:

```
template <char... bits>
struct bin_imp
{
        static constexpr unsigned long long to_ull()
        {
                static_assert(false,"not binary value");
                return 0;
        }
};

template <char... bits>
struct bin_imp<'0', bits...>
{
        static constexpr unsigned long long to_ull()
        {
                return bin_imp<bits...>::to_ull();
        }
};

template <char... bits>
struct bin_imp<'1', bits...>
{
        static constexpr unsigned long long to_ull()
        {
                return (1ULL << sizeof...(bits)) | bin_imp<bits...>::to_ull();
        }
};


template <>
struct bin_imp<>
{
        static constexpr unsigned long long to_ull()
        {
                return 0;
        }
};

template <char... bits>
static constexpr unsigned long long operator "" _b ()
{
        return bin_imp<bits...>::to_ull();
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
        unsigned int i = 11_b;
        return 0;
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
static_assert(false,"not binary value");
```

The compiler rejects this because it is *obvious* to the compiler that it will fail, even during the first phase of parsing the source code. The compiler doesn't need to instantiate the class template, in order to know that the `static_assert` will fail.

What you can do here is, force the compiler to evaluate the condition in the second phase of parsing — i.e when the function (of the class template) is instantiated. To do that you need a class template, such as this:

```
 template<char ...>
 struct always_false : std::false_type {};
```

Now use this as:

```
static_assert(always_false<bits...>::value,"not binary value");
```

Now the compiler cannot evaluate the condition *until* it instantiates `always_false<>` which happens to be always false.

That is, the solution is : **being lazy** when evaluating the expression.

Comment: Another variant I've seen is `sizeof...(bits)==-1`.

Answer (score 3):

As the `static_assert` is independent of the template parameters, compiler can static assert before instantiate it.

To solve your problem, you may use:

```
template <char... bits> struct bin_imp;
```

or

```
template <char... bits>
struct bin_imp
{
    static constexpr unsigned long long to_ull() = delete;
};
```

Comment: Thanks the info! I didn't pick your answer because Nawaz proposed a solution that better matched my situation.

Answer (score -1):

static_assert fails if the first argument does not evaluate to true (see [this](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_cast), section *Boolean conversions*)

Since you are using the boolean value `false`, it will fail.

Since the static_assert does not depend on a template argument, the compiler evaluates it, independent of the scope, and as such, failing the assert. If you use a dynamic assert (`#include <cassert>` and `assert(expr)`), you will see that the code works just fine. Test: http://rextester.com/live/HCT76663

Comment: Assert is not checked at compile-time.

Comment: You did not state that it is required to assert during compilation.

Comment: Well I was using static_assert for a reason.

Comment: And you did not said such reason, for me it seems that you used it just to test if the code works.

Comment: It is used to make sure that the literal will only contain 1s and 0s. Hence the "Not a binary value" part.

Comment: Very well, then this won't help and Nawas has the solution.